# Passing Powershell Securestring to 7zip, but archive cannot be unpacked afterwards

Tags: powershell, password-protection, 7zip

A Powershell script that backups my data reads the password from commandline and passes it to 7zip (7z):

```
....
$pw = Read-Host -assecurestring -Prompt 'Input Backup Master Passphrase: '
$pw = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pw))
....
& 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' a -v900M -t7z -mhe=on -mx=9 -p$pw $target/myarchive.7z $src
```

But when I open the archive in 7zip (GUI) it shows me a password prompt, and after entering the password it shows a single file (again a 7zip file) which is also encrypted, but does not respond to the password.

When I extract the file in another Powershell script it works fine.

```
# $pw is read again from commandline via Read-Host....&PtrToStringAuto
& 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' x -p$pw $target/myarchive.7z
```

Why does the extraction only work on CLI, and not via GUI?

Comment: In the GUI are you entering the plaintext, or encrypted password?

Comment: I am entering plaintext. As the second line (SecureStringToBSTR) should "decrypt" the Secure String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much experimentation (For Science!), I've discovered that the 7z line isn't working as expected. In the original code, the `-p$pw` actually set the password to a literal `$pw`.

The quick & dirty method is to use `Invoke-Expression` instead:

```
$inpw = Read-Host -assecurestring -Prompt 'Input Backup Master Passphrase: '
$zpw = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($inpw))

$archive = "myarchive.7z"
$src = "testfile.txt"
# using a string formatter to avoid a mess of escaping characters 
Invoke-Expression ('& "{0}" a -v900M -t7z -mhe=on -mx=9 -p{1} {2} {3}' -f 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe', $zpw, $archive, $src)
```

However, this has repurcussions with string interpolation and other security/data concerns. You can also look at `Start-Process`, or using the .NET `Process.Start` method for even more control.